# Flutter - String check for ellipsis

Tags: string, dart, flutter, ellipsis

My flutter apps displays description strings which are fetched from a third party, thus these descriptions may already be fitted with ellipsis as to lead the story onwards but the api only fetches around 7 lines or so of the description.

I want every description to contain an ellipsis but don't want to add ellipsis to strings that already contain them.

I want to turn this

> scan the face of each account holder as

into this

> scan the face of each account holder as...

but if the original already contains this ellipsis, it should be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String input = 'your string';

if (!input.endsWith('...')) {
  input += '...';
}
```

Key here is `String.endsWith()`, it's the easiest way to know if the content already ends with an ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced answered from @greyaurora

- be careful trailing space, e.g. `my data...`
- be careful with different ways to display ellipsis, e.g. `...` (3 dots ) vs `…` (1-char ellipsis)

```
void main() {
  String input = 'your string';
  String trimmed = input.trim();

  if (!trimmed.endsWith('...') && !trimmed.endsWith('…')) {
    trimmed += '…';
  }
  print('hello ${trimmed}');
}
```